# How to consume a json object in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

This may be simple to some but I am a newbie in PHP and json and was wondering how do I consume such a cURL below. Like save the data in a database in PHP. Anyone? Thank you.

```
curl -i \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -u username:password \
 -d '{
        "service_name" : "MPESA",
        "business_number" : "888555",
        "transaction_reference" : "DE45GK45",


      }' \
"http://your_domain.com/transaction_consumer"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps to take:
1. load the JSON data
2. understand the JSON data
3. load the data in a database

Your code appears to load the JOSN data using curl. In my experience, curl is powerful but complex for beginners. Probable file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php works as well and is more easy.

e.g.
    $json_data = file_get_contents("URL TO DATA");

Second, there are some JSON function in PHP. I like the json_decode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. e.g. by using

```
$array = (json_decode($json_data, true));
```

to get the data in an array.

Third, this totale depends on the database setup (mysql?). Make sure you have a connection, a database and a table. Then you can use an insert query and insert the data from the $array.